# App crash on IBOutlet UIView addSubView after upgrading to IOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

On Xcode 6 when I run my app on iOS 7.x or 8.x simulator or device it works, but after i upgraded my xCode to v7 and run my app on iOS 9 devices or simulator, it crash when I call the method addSubView in UIView.

My app works as the following, the launcher UIController is empty,
and in storyboard i referenced an IBOutlet UIView.

Story Board:

[image: View Controller]

[image: Controller Outline]

[image: Outlet referencing]

.h File:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *detailView;
```

.m File:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    if(!_currentViewController)
         _currentViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC_Initiation"];   

    [self addChildViewController:_currentViewController];
    [_detailView addSubview:_currentViewController.view];
    [_currentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

The application close directly after this line executed:

```
  [_detailView addSubview:_currentViewController.view];
```

can anyone help me and explain to me what is the difference between running this code on iOS 8 and iOS 9 ??

Comment: whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Aris after i upgraded to xCode 7 i get no errors or call stack on Debug Navigation and when my app terminate on this line no errors appear on Outputs console

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception breakpoint? I find it odd that the app could exit like that.

Comment: Did you currentViewController initial successfully?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Xcode 7, target is iOS8. Clean UIView, previously used removeFromSuperview on an array of the views contents. The view is visible and empty, addsubview causes the crash. The addSubview line is highlighted, exception breakpoint is set however no error is shown. No failure message. The only indication of failure is the app is frozen (when connected to xCode) or dead when not. Only console output is (lldb)